# Is there a principled approach to dimensionality reduction?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

**Background**

I have walked around my office environment with a video camera. From these image sequences, I wish to determine whether or not there is a 2D embedding that approximates the camera's trajectory or the geometry of the floor plan or its semantics (i.e. offices vs corridors vs kitchen, etc).

The images are converted into feature vectors of ~500D each. I have tested a variety of nonlinear dimensionality reduction techniques to reduce the dataset to 2D for visualisation, however the approach of selecting and testing such techniques does not seem very methodical. The resources that I have on dimensionality reduction simply provide a set of techniques with very little discussion on a general overarching approach.

**Question**

Is there a principled approach to dimensionality reduction or does one generally need to approach it heuristically (more or less what I am currently doing)?

In either case, could some suggestions be provided as to how one should approach dimensionality reduction with particular reference to the problem that I am exploring?